# When is FileDescriptor closed?

Tags: java, android, file-descriptor, fileinputstream

My app needs to do the following:

- Open a `FileInputStream`, and obtain the underlying `FileDescriptor` (via `getFd()`)
- Create new `FileInputStream` objects based on the above `FileDescriptor`

So far, I only needed one `FileDescriptor`, so I used to close it by calling `close()` on the original stream (i.e. on the stream which `getFd()` I called). I use it because some Android API methods have such a parameter.

Now that I will have more `FileInputStream` objects at the same time, when will the `FileDescriptor` be closed? (My guess: when all `FileInputStream` objects are closed?)

Comment: This seems like something you could test?

Comment: You're right, I initially had no idea how to detect that it's closed, but now I can think of something, and Jiri Patera also gave an option in his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I belive you are right. A small test shows that the `FileDescriptor` becomes invalid after its `FileInputStream` is closed. Note that, in case of more than one `FileInputStream` for the same `FileDescriptor`, the `FileDescriptor` becomes invalid as soon as its first `FileInputStream` is closed, i.e. it does not matter if you close first `fis1` and then `fis2` or the other way around:

```
FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream("/tmp/adb.log");
FileDescriptor fd = fis1.getFD();
FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(fd);
System.out.println(fd.valid());
fis1.close();
System.out.println(fd.valid());
fis2.close();
System.out.println(fd.valid());
```

Output is:

```
true
false
false
```

Do not forget to close the stream in a `finally` block, to make sure you close it also in case of an I/O (read/write) error.

Comment: Thanks, this answers a part of my question. The remaning part is that if you create *more* FileInputStream objects based on your *fd*, when does *fd* become invalid? Based on Android source that I just checked, I have an interesting suspicion but it would be nice if you could test it first (now that you already have the environment set up).

Comment: BTW the "interesting suspicion" I have based on Android source code: *FileInputStream* objects that were created based on an *fd* will not touch it when closed; the *fd* will be closed when the original *FileInputStream* is closed (with no regard to any other open *FileInputStream* instances). This is what the Androud source code (v2.2) implies, at least.

Answer (score 0):

Android `FileInputStream` has a concept of fd ownership.

isFdOwner is true when you create the stream from File.
Is it false when you create it from existing `FileDescriptor`.
(actually there is a hidden constructor which allows you to specify
whether the new stream is also an owner or not,
but 'false' works great in almost all situations)

If you close `FileInputStream` that was opened with `File` - it will be closed.
Closing streams that were opened with fd - will do nothing.