# How to create a FileChannel from a FileDescriptor?

Tags: java, android

I know I can just do `new FileInputStream(fd).getChannel()` but this will close the FileDescriptor passed in. Is there a way to do so without any side effect?

Comment: How would it close the `FileDescriptor`? `FileDescriptor` isn't `AutoCloseable`.

Comment: The new FileInputSteam is closed when garbage collected, then it closes the associated FileDescriptor. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/17263278

Comment: Oh. So where do you get the `FileDescriptor`? It looks like you can only get it from an already open Stream. I'd guess the reason for this behavior is that the FD is pretty much synonymous with the `Stream` it's been opened from.

Comment: Yes it’s from another FileInputStream

Comment: The JDK implementation has improved significantly in recent releases. The underlying file descriptor will not be closed if there is a FileChannel to it.